# How do I fix this syntax error when using a function within another function?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out how to call the function within another function, but I am unable to solve this invalid syntax error on line "t_calc = calc_temp(d_curr,volt,tbase)." Can you not call a function within another function?

```
def calc_temp(current,voltage,tbase):
    power_diss = current * voltage
    thermal_resistance = THICK/(K*AREA)
    temp = tbase + (power_diss * thermal_resistance)
    return(temp)


def diode_i_terr(volt,tguess,tbase):
    d_curr = I0(np.exp((Q*volt)/(IDE*KB*tguess))
    t_calc = calc_temp(d_curr,volt,tbase)
    t_err = t_calc - tguess
    return(d_curr, t_err)



    t_calc = calc_temp(d_curr,volt,tbase)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Missing parenthesis on `d_curr = I0(np.exp((Q*volt)/(IDE*KB*tguess)))`

Comment: Wow! Thank you, I did not see that.